# Azure Active Directory single sign-on (SSO) integration with Sugar CRM - redirects to index.php

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, sugarcrm

my Azure Active Directory single sign-on (SSO) integration with Sugar CRM - redirects to index.php
this is my configuration

I tried to add /home to relay state and tried to change entityid , but it is not working .

i have gone through documentation , what more can i try

[image]

Comment: You need to allow popup on your browser. When it redirects to index page Azure AD login popup will appear. Which'll let you key-in azure login details.

Answer (score 0):

•   I would suggest you to please check the sign-on URL and the reply URL formats as they should be according to the account registered in Sugar CRM. The sign-on URL is the URL where your page will be redirected to when you click the ‘Test this application’ button. Thus, it should be in the same format as specified in the documentation as below: -
[image: Sign-on URL]

Since sign-on URL is the page when it redirects first when testing the application, it should be correct and reachable. Also, for convenience purposes, download the federation metadata file from your Sugar CRM admin account and upload it directly in your Sugar CRM application created in your Azure AD tenant as below. This will import and configure all the SAML SSO settings correctly.

[image: Upload metadata file]

For exporting the federation metadata file from Sugar CRM, please follow the below link and configure it accordingly: -

https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/SugarCloud_Services/SugarIdentity/SugarIdentity_Guide/#Exporting_Metadata_File